# Quotes on Helvetica CSS font

Tags: css

I want to use Helvetica in a font-family list like

```
font-family: 'Helvetica', Arial, sans-serif;
```

Thing is that sometimes I notice that people put Helvetica in quotes and sometimes they don't.

Can anyone shed light on why ?

Answer (score 4):

It really is just a matter of preference, as there are no spaces like in `"Times New Roman"` the quotes are completely optional, Just a matter of what they are used to...

Answer (score 2):

Quotes are necessary only when font name contains whitespaces. Even [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#declaration) don't quote Helvetica.

Answer (score 1):

Quotes enable multi word font names, like 'Sans Serif' or 'Times New Roman'.
Since **Helvetica** is a single word, quotes are not necessary.